# How do I mirror a google sheet row to another sheet's in different array?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

As I have to frequently send whatsapp to sales when customers pop in, is there anyway i can create a template when i input the ID , it will automatically render the message into the following format?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj0Dn.jpg

Comment: Yes. Use `transpose`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index and match along with transpose to make it vertical:

```
=transpose(Index(F:H, match(J1,E:E)))
```

[image]